# Gradle Build Run error (DebugUtils.class) in Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-support-library

I'm getting the following error

Error:Execution failed for task

> :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/util/DebugUtils.class

I searched the entire day but couldn't found a proper answer which will solve my problem.

My app bulid gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.project.test"
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

// depend files

```
dependencies 
{ 
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' 
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1' 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+' 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+' 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+' 
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') 
    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
}
```

I tried Clean and Rebuild, but that also not working.
Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')` row from the dependencies? It seems it is already added as a dependency in the fileTree row.

Comment: yes tried that also adrian. Not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens when you add the same class twice.

In your project you are adding many times the support-v4 library.

- remove `android-support-v4.jar` from libs folder
- remove this line `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')`
- change the dependency of the library 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1' because it uses an old support-v4.jar

Use:

```
compile ('com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1') {
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research it seams that `com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1` is [already importing](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/library/libs) the `android-support-v4.jar`, from here your duplicate error. In order to fix it I recommend you to do the following changes:

- remove `android-support-v4.jar` from libs folder
- remove from gradle file the line `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')`.

Hope it fixes your problem.